# How to get parent element with attribute using xpath

Tags: xpath, xquery, marklogic

I have posted sample XML and expected output kindly help to get the result.

Sample XML

```
<root>
  <A id="1">
    <B id="2"/>
    <C id="2"/>
  </A>
</root>
```

Expected output:

```
<A id="1"/>
```

Comment: you need parent element of <A id=1>?

Comment: Yes @vitally...

Comment: ok, answered, @antony

Comment: I am not get the correct result.

Answer (score 6):

You can formulate this query in several ways:

- Find elements that have a matching attribute, only ascending all the time:

  ```
  //*[@id=1]
  ```
- Find the attribute, then ascend a step:

  ```
  //@id[.=1]/..
  ```
- Use the `fn:id($id)` function, given the document is validated and the ID-attribute is defined as such:

  ```
  /id('1')
  ```

Comment: You cannot get the exact result you asked for, as all XML elements must be closed. So best you could get is `<a id='1' />`. It seems I (and the others) understood the question wrongly. What are the rules on how to select the result?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not possible what you're after. There's no way of selecting a node without its children using XPATH (meaning that it'd always return the nodes B and C in your case)

You could achieve this using XQuery, I'm not sure if this is what you want but here's an example where you create a new node based on an existing node that's stored in the `$doc` variable.

```
declare variable $doc := <root><A id="1"><B id="2"/><C id="2"/></A></root>;
element {fn:node-name($doc/*)} {$doc/*/@*}
```

The above returns `<A id="1"></A>`.

Comment: This answer addresses what I think is the intended question, however may not generalise. Maybe the second line should be `for $el in $doc//*[@id="1"] return element { fn:node-name($el) } { $el/@* }`

Answer (score 0):

is that what you are looking for?

`//*[@id='1']/parent::*` , similar to `//*[@id='1']/../`

if you want to verify that parent is root :

```
//*[@id='1']/parent::root
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath
if you need not just parent - but previous element with some attribute: Read about Axis specifiers and use Axis "ancestor::" =)